# How can I play an MP4 video on the Pi?

Tags: video, omxplayer

Does anyone know the steps to play an MP4 video from a USB stick? When I insert the stick, I see the file on file manager but can't get it to play. I would like to set it up for looping with a schedule in between each time it starts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

From a terminal window to play a video once - examples :

```
omxplayer file.mp4
omxplayer /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264
omxplayer /media/pi/4D4F-2594/TV/MaxHeadroom5War.m4v
```

To loop a video from a terminal window :

```
while true; do omxplayer /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264; sleep 1; done
```